# About compile servlets from command line: the provided solution didn't work

Tags: java, windows, servlets, cmd

I'm trying to compile my servlet file from command line:
the command I type is:

```
javac -classpath E:\Programs\JavaEE\apache-tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.72-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.72\lib\servlet-api.jar DemoServlet.java
```

This is the method provided by most of the resources that I have seen online.
However, this doesn't work. The error happens as following:
[image]
So what's wrong with it? What did I miss?

Comment: does the servlet-api jar file really exists in that folder ? Are you sure you're using a jdk javac and not some windows quirk stub command ?

Comment: yes, the file really exists, and the javac is jdk javac. I copied the path from address line. And I can use javac to compile a simple .java file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that servlet-api.jar exist in the folder and try to provide the complete package name of your Servlet(if your servlet class is in pacakge,eg `com/john/DemoServlet`) class.run the below command

```
javac -classpath .;E:\Programs\JavaEE\apache-tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.72-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.72\lib\servlet-api.jar com/john/DemoServlet.java
```

Comment: After I copied the jar file to the same folder of DemoServlet.java, and change the class path to current folder, it works.

Comment: But I'm quite sure the original path is correct, so maybe there are some invalid characters in the original path?

Comment: find it our, I typed the tomcat-api.jar instead of servlet-api.jar... sorry for the stupid mistake